# Minimal number of algebra generators of a group ring

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $k$ be a commutative ring with unit and let $(A,\varepsilon)$ be a (not necessarily commutative) augmented, finitely generated $k$-algebra with augmentation ideal $I$.

If $\mu(A)$ denotes the minimal number of algebra generators of $A$ and $\mu(I)$ the minimal number of generators of $I$ as ideal, we have $\mu(I) \le \mu(A)$.

(For, if $A$ is generated as algebra by $x_1,...,x_n$, then it's also generated by $y_i := x_i - \varepsilon(x_i)\cdot 1\in I$. If $y$ is any element in $I$, write $y = a + f\langle y_1,...,y_n\rangle$ where $a \in k$ and $f$ is a polynomial in the (noncommuting) vaiables $y_1,..,y_n$ having no constant term. Hence $0=\varepsilon(y)=\varepsilon(a)=a$, i.e. $y = f\langle y_1,...,y_n\rangle$ is in the ideal generated by $(y_1,...,y_n)$. This shows $I=(y_1,...,y_n)$ and hence $\mu(I) \le n$)

I wonder what can be said in the case of group algebras:

**Question:** Does for finitely generated groups the equality 
$\mu(\mathbb{Z}[G]) = \mu(I)$ hold ?

Note: If $\mu(G)$ denotes the minimal number of generators of the group $G$, we have for finite $G$: 
$$\mu(I) \le \mu(\mathbb{Z}[G])  \le \mu(G).$$
So the equality would follow from $\mu(I)=\mu(G)$ but I don't know if the latter is true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The paper [The presentation rank of a direct product of finite groups](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869374900623) by Cossey, Gruenberg and Kovacs shows that the difference between the minimal number of generators of $G$ and  $I$ can be as big as you like for finite groups.

Comment: Great! Thank you. The paper also let's construct simple explicit examples:  Let $H\neq 1$ be a finite solvable group and let $G = H^k$ be the direct product. Then $\mu(I_H)=\mu(H)$ (p. 597 and Prop. 1) and $\mu(I_G)=\mu(I_H)$ (Theorem 2). Hence $\mu(\mathbb{Z}[G]) = k\cdot \mu(\mathbb{Z}[H])=k\cdot \mu(I_H) = k\cdot \mu(I_G) > \mu(I_G)$ for $k> 1$.

Comment: BTW: The paper gives a cohomological formula for $\mu(I)$. Do you know if there is also some kind of formula/characterization for $\mu(\mathbb{Z}[G])$ ?

Comment: I don't think there is any such formula